# Uniform convergence of $f_n$ on a compact implies uniform convergence on some $\delta$-enlargement of this compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, compactness

We have $(D,d)$ a metric space, $K$ a compact of D.
$f_n$ is a decreasing sequence of positive real-valued continuous bounded functions on $D$ that converges uniformly to $0$ on $K$ and pointwise to $0$ on $D$. We define $K^\delta = \{ x \in D : d(x,K) < \delta \}$. How can one show that there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $f_n$ converges uniformly to $0$ on $K^\delta$. I feel like we should use uniform continuity on $K$, but I don't see where.

Comment: What does "decreasing" mean?  Do you mean $f_{n + 1} \leq f_{n}$?

Comment: Exactly, this is it

Comment: It might be easier to understand if you wrote "decreasing sequence of positive ..." instead of "sequence of positive decreasing...."

Comment: Note: The uniform convergence part is not needed in the sense that it is implied: pointwise convergence of monotone function on compact set is uniform. However, it is nice that I didn't have to prove it separately. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true without further assumptions on $D$.

For example, it's true if $D$ is locally compact, as clark already alluded to.  Indeed, if $x \in K$, then there is a $\delta_{x} > 0$ such that $B(x,\delta)$ is pre-compact.  Then, by Dini's Theorem, $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $\overline{B(x,\delta)}$.  By compactness, we can cover $K$ by finitely many of these open balls.  Call their union $U$.  Appealing to compactness again, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $K \subseteq K^{\delta} \subseteq U$.  By construction, $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly on $U$ so it converges uniformly on $K^{\delta}$.

To see this isn't true in general, take $D = \ell^{1}(\mathbb{N})$ with the metric induced by the norm.  For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define a linear functional $F_{n} : \ell^{1}(\mathbb{N}) \to \ell^{1}(\mathbb{N})$ by
$$F_{n}(x_{1},x_{2},\dots) = \left(\frac{x_{1}}{n}, \frac{x_{2}}{n^{\frac{1}{2}}}, \dots, \frac{x_{j}}{n^{\frac{1}{j}}},\dots\right).$$  Observe that $\|F_{n}\| =1$.  Thus, $(F_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are continuous functions.  Finally, define $f_{n} : \ell^{1}(\mathbb{N}) \to \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ by
$$f_{n}(x_{1},x_{2},\dots) = \sum_{j = 1}^{\infty} \frac{|x_{j}|}{n^{\frac{1}{j}}} = \|F_{n}(x_{1},x_{2},\dots)\|_{\ell^{1}(\mathbb{N})}.$$
$(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of continuous functions on $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{N})$ converging pointwise to zero.  Moreover, since the sum defining $f_{n}$ decreases termwise, it follows that $f_{n + 1} \leq f_{n}$.  Thus, $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a decreasing sequence of non-negative continuous functions that converges pointwise to zero on $\ell^{1}(\mathbb{N})$, which is what we're looking for.

(For my fellow pedants, if we insist on a sequence of *positive* functions, we can instead use $$g_{n}(x_{1},x_{2},\dots) = f_{n}(x_{1},x_{2},\dots) + n^{-1},$$ which is a decreasing sequence of positive continuous functions.  The arguments that follow work for $(g_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ just as much as they work for $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.)

Now let $K = \{0\}$.  I claim that if $\delta > 0$, then $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge uniformly on $B(0,\delta)$.  To see this, fix $\delta > 0$ and let $\{e_{j}\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ denote the sequences 
$$e_{1} = (1,0,0,\dots), \, \, e_{2} = (0,1,0,\dots), \dots$$
Observe that if $n, j \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$, then $\lambda \delta e_{j} \in B(0,\delta)$ and
$$f_{n}(\lambda \delta e_{j}) = \lambda \delta n^{-\frac{1}{j}}.$$
By taking $j \to \infty$ and $\lambda \to 1$, we obtain
$$\sup \{f_{n}(x) \, \mid \, \ x \in B(0,\delta)\} = \delta.$$
Thus, $(f_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does not converge to zero uniformly on $B(0,\delta)$.  Since $K^{\delta} = B(0,\delta)$, this concludes the proof.

Comment: Either you just found that Van Der Vaart made a mistake in his "Weak convergence and empirical processes" book (he uses the statement to prove a general version of prohorov's theorem page 22) or there is something wrong that I am not seeing. (you can see the part where he's using this without proving it here https://gyazo.com/5ca92c33067eb733b98b34a80b4044e5 )

Comment: Is $D$ locally compact?  What is $D$?  It's true that $|f_{m}(x)| \leq 2 \epsilon$ if $x \in K^{\delta_{m}}$, where $\delta = \delta_{m}$ depends on $m$.  Could that be what he meant?  Based on the paragraph you provided, it's hard to parse.

Comment: $D$ is a general metric space where $K$ and its enlargement are living in. Maybe he meant that $\delta$ depends on $m$. How can you prove that it's true if $\delta$ depends on $m$ ?

Comment: How can you prove *what* is true if $\delta$ depends on $m$?  I don't understand your question.  I think it might be worth asking a different question specifically about the proof in Van Der Vaart's book.

Comment: You said that it's true that $|f_m(x)| \le 2\epsilon$ if $x \in K^\delta$ where $\delta = \delta_m$ depends on $m$. How do you know that ?

Comment: Consider the case when $K = \{x_{0}\}$.  If $|f_{m}(x_{0})| \leq \epsilon$, then there is a $\delta_{m} > 0$ such that $|f_{m}(x)| \leq 2 \epsilon$ whenever $x \in B(x_{0},\delta_{m}) = K^{\delta}$.  In general, we can find such a ball at each point of $K$, then use compactness to cover $K$ by a union of finitely many such balls.

Comment: I will try to write down the proof, I'll come back to you if I have a problem. Thank you very much !